# How do I get Mathematica to thread a 2-variable function over two lists, using functional programming techniques?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, wolfram-mathematica

Lets say I have a function `f[x_, y_]`, and two lists `l1`, `l2`. I'd like to evaluate `f[x,y]` for each pair `x,y` with `x` in `l1` and `y` in `l2`, and I'd like to do it *without* having to make all pairs of the form `{l1[[i]],l2[[j]]}`.

Essentially, what I want is something like Map[Map[f[#1, #2]&, l1],l2] where #1 takes values from l1 and #2 takes values from l2, but this doesn't work.

(Motivation: I'm trying to implement some basic Haskell programs in Mathematica. In particular, I'd like to be able to code the Haskell program

```
isMatroid::[[Int]]->Bool
isMatroid b =and[or[sort(union(xs\\[x])[y]'elem'b|y<-ys]|xs<-b,ys<-b, xs<-x]
```

I think I can do the rest of it, if I can figure out the original question, but I'd like the code to be Haskell-like. Any suggestions for implementing Haskell-like code in Mathematica would be appreciated.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To evaluate a function `f` over all pairs from two lists `l1` and `l2`, use [`Outer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Outer.html):

```
In[1]:=  Outer[f, {a,b}, {x,y,z}]
Out[1]:= {{f[a,x],f[a,y],f[a,z]}, {f[b,x],f[b,y],f[b,z]}}
```

`Outer` by default works at the lowest level of the provided lists; you can also specify a level with an additional argument:

```
In[2]:=  Outer[f, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}, 1]
Out[2]:= {{f[{1,2},{a,b}], f[{1,2},{c,d}]}, {f[{3,4},{a,b}], f[{3,4},{c,d}]}}
```

Note that this produces a nested list; you can `Flatten` it if you like.

My original answer pointed to [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html) and [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapThread.html), which are two ways to apply a function to corresponding pairs from lists, e.g. `MapThread[f,{a,b},{1,2}] == {f[a,1], f[b,2]}`.

P.S. I think as you're learning these things, you'll find the documentation very helpful. There are a lot of general topic pages, for example, [applying functions to lists](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ApplyingFunctionsToLists.html) and [list manipulation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ListManipulation.html). These are generally linked to in the "more about" section at the bottom of specific documentation. This makes it a lot easier to find things when you don't know what they'll be called.

Comment: Neither of these works, though: if l1 = {1,2,3}, l2 = {x,y,z}, I want to evaluate f[x,y] on the 9 possible pairs (1,x), (1, y), ...,(3,y),  (3,z). Both Thread and MapThread suck in elements at the same position in the two lists.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I misunderstood what you meant by "runs over". You'll want `Outer` then; it'll take me a minute to edit the answer up.

Comment: @Leah: You're welcome! I'm still hoping someone will chime in about Haskell and Mathematica - I've been meaning to learn Haskell at some point.

Answer (score 3):

To pick up on OP's request for suggestions about implementing Haskell-like code in Mathematica.  A couple of things you'll have to deal with are:

- Haskell evaluates lazily, by default Mathematica does not, it's very eager.  You'll need to wrestle with Hold[] and its relatives to write lazily evaluating functions, but it can be done.  You can also subvert Mathematica's evaluation process and tinker with Prolog and Epilog and such like.
- Haskell's type system and type checking are probably more rigorous than Mathematica's defaults, but Mathematica does have the features to implement strict type checking.

I'm sure there's a lot more but I'm not terribly familiar with Haskell.

Answer (score 0):

In[1]:= list1 = Range[1, 5];

In[2]:= list2 = Range[6, 10];

In[3]:= (f @@ #) & /@ Transpose[{list1, list2}]

Out[3]= {f[1, 6], f[2, 7], f[3, 8], f[4, 9], f[5, 10]}

Comment: @ragfield: This was my first thought as well, but Leah explicitly said "*without* having to make all pairs..." - so Transpose is out.